# filter out data from file on the basis of other in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, gawk

I have a big file having 50s columns and 100K of rows delimited by `|`. Now `$2`(col 2) has multiple type of `$1`(col 1) value which means col 2 will be repeated. So I have sorted the file.
I need now to extract/filter the result file on the basis of below condition:

- condition 1 : when `$2` has both type of `$1` (value of `$1` for `$2` is more than 8000 as well as less than 8000) then select the complete row which is for `$1` < 8000 for the given `$2`
- condition 2: if `$2` has only `$1 > 8000` then select the complete row which is having max `$8` value

**E.g: source file**

```
4000|1234||||||23
5000|1234||||||22
9000|1234||||||25
10000|123|||||||22
22000|456|||||||27
15000|456|||||||29
```

result file would have:

```
9000|1234||||||25
10000|123|||||||23
15000|456|||||||29
```

Can anyone please advice on this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is `22000` not in output?

Comment: Why is 22000 not in output?  ANS--  Because $2(456) has values only >8000 so row selected on the basis of $9 (29) having max value as 29>27

Comment: It is unclear, why is `123` row not showing `22` in last column?

Comment: What is the meaning of " when `$2` has both type of `$1`"?

Comment: The wording is unclear.  `Now $2(col 2) has multiple type of $1(col 1) value which means col 2 will be repeated. ` -- what does `multiple type` mean?

Comment: agc ---  as you can see column 2 ($2) has in one to many relation with column 1 ( $1). this is what i mean .  Please let me know is it clear now???

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ANSWER:I got...

```
 sort -n -t\| -k2 -k1 < sortexp.txt |awk -F\| '$1 < 8000 { a[$2]++ ; print } $1 >= 8000 { if ( !a[$2] && ( !e[$2] || e[$2]<$8 ))  {u[$2]=$0;e[$2]=$8;} ; } END { for ( i in u ) print u[i] ;}'
```